# DDL for PostgreSQL for DB2 tables (migration)

Tags: postgresql, migration, ddl, db2-zos

How would I create the DDL for PostgreSQL for the following DB2 tables?
It should be a one-to-one migration, so I would like to change only as little as possible at the schema (I have difficulties with the BLOB/CLOB datatypes and the default values).

```
CREATE TABLE table1
(
   field_1  DECIMAL(15)   NOT NULL,
   field_2  ROWID         NOT NULL WITH DEFAULT,
   field_3  DECIMAL(15)   NOT NULL WITH DEFAULT,
   field_4  BLOB          NOT NULL WITH DEFAULT,
   field_5  TIMESTAMP     NOT NULL WITH DEFAULT,
   field_6  INTEGER       NOT NULL WITH DEFAULT,
   field_7  VARCHAR(64)   NOT NULL WITH DEFAULT,
   field_8  SMALLINT      NOT NULL WITH DEFAULT,
   field_9  CHAR(60)      NOT NULL WITH DEFAULT,
   field_10 DATE          NOT NULL WITH DEFAULT,
   field_11 DECIMAL(12,3) NOT NULL WITH DEFAULT,
   field_12 TIME          NOT NULL WITH DEFAULT,
   field_13 BIGINT        NOT NULL WITH DEFAULT
);
```

Second table:

```
CREATE TABLE table2
(
   field_1  DECIMAL(15)     NOT NULL,
   field_2  ROWID           NOT NULL,
   field_3  VARCHAR(2500)   NOT NULL,
   field_4  CLOB
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BLOB` should be translated to `bytea` in Postgres and `CLOB` to `text`.

`DECIMAL(15)` is probably better done as `bigint` and `char()` should not be used at all. I would replace that with `varchar(30)`

I don't know what `rowid` is in DB2.

The `with default` option is invalid for Postgres. If you want a default value you need to specify it explicitly, e.g.:

```
field_6  INTEGER       NOT NULL DEFAULT 42,
```

Comment: And `varchar(60)` only if there realy should be a limit, otherwise `varchar` or `text`.  The same definitely applies to the present `varchar(2500)` column.

Comment: @dezso: `varchar(60)` seems to make sense as a business constraint. I would also keep the `varchar(2500)` assuming that the programs that use the data rely on the fact that the values will never be longer

Comment: You might be totally right, but I am yet to see any real constraint on the length where it is longer than 100 characters (about).